# Automatically delete orphaned SIDs

Tags: remove, sid, orphans

Does someone know a tool that allows to delete orphaned SIDs on a fileserver without the need for any scripting?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Server Fault. We require posts to be in English. A Google translation would do. If you post the German as well someone will be able to correct any translation errors.

Comment: @SvenW I'm 85% certain this can be done with PowerShell, giving him a script would probably be as good as a tool...  (and Thomas: Don't be afraid of scripting. Microsoft FINALLY gave you PowerShell - A scripting language that doesn't suck - You should use it as much as practical)

Comment: You can use "SetACL -on D:\ -ot file -actn delorphanedsids" as described here https://helgeklein.com/blog/2012/07/finding-removing-orphaned-sids-in-file-permissions-or-busting-the-ghosts-built-into-windows-7/  You may have to download setacl from https://helgeklein.com/setacl/

Answer (score 3):

You could download [SubInACL](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23510).

You can use the following format to clean out orpahned SID's

```
/cleandeletedsidsfrom=domain[=dacl|sacl|owner|primarygroup|all]
```

If you want this done automagically you can create a script, though I have never done so myself.